# "I was going to" expression. How to use it correctly?

Tags: grammar, expressions, will-be-going, future-in-past

> I was going to pick you tomorrow from the airport (not a big deal to me,
>   really), but remembered that tomorrow I'll be teaching the class, which ends at
>   8.

in above example, I am trying to say that earlier I planned to pick you up (tomorrow), but now I remember that I have prior commitments tomorrow, and hence can longer do it.

What's the best way to say something like this and use *I was going* expression.

thnkas

Comment: “I was going to pick you tomorrow from the airport” sounds perfectly fine to me.  What’s wrong with that?  If I am not mistaken, “I’ll be teaching” should be “I would be teaching” (and “which ends at 8” should be “which would end at 8”??  not so sure about this…) because “remembered” is the past tense.  (I am not a native speaker of English.)

Comment: By the way, I would say “I was going to pick you up at the airport tomorrow.”

Comment: "I'll be teaching" is fine because we are talking about a time that will happen in the future (tomorrow) at the time the message is read.  If the teaching already happened by the time the message is read, then you would need to change to "would be teaching".

Comment: Teaching will only happen tomorrow, I planned yesterday, and I wrote this message today.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: I did not know that.  Thanks!

Comment: Some information about this in general is at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_of_tenses#English. However, I may say that what is described there as the "Natural sequence" is not any part of any English that I recognise; I believe it to have been invented by people labouring under the misapprehension that any rule of Latin grammar must apply to English.

Comment: This may help also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_tense#Expressions_of_relative_tense . What you're describing is called "future of the past".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds fine the way you have it (except for the "pick you *up* tomorrow" part). I guess you could change it to

> I had planned to pick you up tomorrow […].

and it sounds a little more formal.